# How to Schedule silent push notification in objective c?

Tags: ios

> I want to schedule the silent push notification, and perform some
>    action on that. How  can i implement this?

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial

Comment: First push notification are send from a server, so you will need to tell us how and what kind of server you are using. Then you post what you have tried to solve this issue yourself. As your question is way to broad and does not clearly state what you are expecting, thus your question will 
most likely be closed.